# Is there a way to use a batch file to play a mp4 in a directory

Tags: batch-file, windows-task-scheduler

Im trying to find a way so i can get task scheduler to open a batch file and, to play a video at a specific time of day, but the video changes everyday, but is in the same directory. Im sure i can get a way so it's the only video in the directory when the  command is run. Im using windows 10 and would not mind using mac os or linux

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, your batch file can call windows media player, but it may be easier to install VLC.  Then have your batch file call

```
vlc c:\directory\myvideo.mp4
```

If the file name might change, but you're sure it's the only file in the directory, then do this:

```
for /r %%i in (*) do vlc %%i
```

I believe vlc has a --fullscreen argument.  Make a scheduled task to call the batch file.  Season to taste.

Comment: Honestly, you can just say `start "" "%%i"` and the file will open with whatever the default media player is.